# Cloning a coding gene into a non-expression vector

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, gene-expression

Does it make any sense to clone a CODING gene into a NON-expression vector?
doing this will only give us multiple copies of the gene, while we could run  PCR instead (Let's say we know the gene sequence)

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please take [the tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [how to ask a good question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to provide some context to your question as the reasons for cloning genes are numerous, and your quesition is in danger of being considered too wide. You should also indicate what efforts you have already made to answer the question for yourself. Tell us what you found and why it doesn't fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you can amplify any gene with PCR and then clone it into a vector of choice. However, it is often not as easy. Most things can be done with expression vectors, but sometimes it is easier to clone a sequence first and then subclone it.

Some sequences are hard to amplify, especially when they get long or very long. Amplifying 2,5kb can be tricky, digesting and subcloning such a piece might be easier. Additionally yields of PCR can be low, while you get a lot of DNA from a miniprep.

You might want to introduce additional restriction enzyme recognition sites (one can easily be done via PCR, but more again is tricky), linker or additional tags, which are not present in all expression vectors. Then it is easier to simply do a first cloning step into the non-expression vector and then take the complete insert into the expression vector.